# issue in Converting JFX8 into JFX15

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-11

I recently started working with javafx. I changed the jdk from 8 to 11 and using JAVAFX 15 version in the project and there is a class that uses these method "getCellLength()" and "getViewportLength()" here am getting error like these

The method getViewportLength() from the type VirtualFlow is not visible

The method getCellLength(int) from the type VirtualFlow is not visible

it seems these methods were declared as private in JFX15 version.

double n = forward ? numPixels + pixelOffset - (getViewportLength() * getPosition()) - start
: -numPixels + end - (pixelOffset - (getViewportLength() * getPosition()));

cellSize = getCellLength(cellIndex);

I am not able to resolve these error in JAVAFX 15 code

Comment: You'll probably have to re-write this portion of the code.

Comment: use reflection where needed (the amount of dirt in your code doesn't change as you accessed internal api before ;) Unrelated: please format the code snippets (min. 4 leading spaces in each line, no tabs - select and ctrl-k)